# Mysql Left Join statement ignored during query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a long MySql query that has a lots of filters in it to narrow my results to a small set of answers I need. Here is the query is use at the moment:

```
SELECT o.offer_id, o.external_cat, o.cat, o.shop, o.item_id, o.live
FROM ourson_offerattributes_new oa1
JOIN ourson_offerattributes_new oa2 ON oa1.offer_id=oa2.offer_id
    AND oa1.attribute_id = 'most_recent_status'
JOIN ourson_offerattributes_new oa3 ON oa2.offer_id=oa3.offer_id
    AND oa3.attribute_id = oa2.value AND oa3.value ='OK'
JOIN ourson_offer_new o ON (o.offer_id = oa3.offer_id
    AND cat IN (5051511,5051512,5051513,5051514,5051507,5051508,5051509,5051510,5051505,5051506,5051500,5051501,5051502,5051503,5060402))
LEFT JOIN ourson_offerattributes_new oa4 ON oa3.offer_id=oa4.offer_id
    AND oa4.attribute_id='status_ltu_indexer' AND oa4.value='OK' AND oa3.offer_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN ourson_offer_new oa5 ON oa3.offer_id=oa5.offer_id
    AND oa5.cat IS NULL AND oa5.cat IN (5070101,7030100,2020205,2020202)
```

This query works when I use it, but I've noticed than one of my `LEFT JOIN` clause is totally ignored, I can put any filter in it, MySQL just ignores it and I don't seem to know why as no error are raised...

This is the line that is ignored:

```
LEFT JOIN ourson_offerattributes_new oa4 ON oa3.offer_id=oa4.offer_id
    AND oa4.attribute_id='status_ltu_indexer' AND oa4.value='OK' AND oa3.offer_id IS NULL
```

Could someone help me stop the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably lies in the part:

```
AND oa3.offer_id IS NULL
```

which is never `NULL` beacause of `JOIN` use to connect `oa3` to the result set.

**updated #1:**

Please replace following part of the query:

```
LEFT JOIN ourson_offerattributes_new oa4 ON oa3.offer_id=oa4.offer_id
    AND oa4.attribute_id='status_ltu_indexer' AND oa4.value='OK' AND oa3.offer_id IS NULL
```

with this one:

```
INNER JOIN ourson_offerattributes_new oa4 ON oa3.offer_id=oa4.offer_id
    AND oa4.attribute_id='status_ltu_indexer' AND oa4.value='OK'
```

Also please consider replacing the part:

```
LEFT JOIN ourson_offer_new oa5 ON oa3.offer_id=oa5.offer_id
    AND oa5.cat IS NULL AND oa5.cat IN (5070101,7030100,2020205,2020202)
```

with the:

```
INNER JOIN ourson_offer_new oa5 ON oa3.offer_id=oa5.offer_id
    AND oa5.cat IN (5070101,7030100,2020205,2020202)
```

Comment: I need to test if `oa4.offer_id` is present or not in `oa3` result set, I thought the `IS NULL` statement was here to test this... How could I proceed ?

Comment: I'll try to help you best I can, but could you tell whether this query is hand-written by you or generated through some visual editor?

Comment: Could you also explain, why would you need to know whether `oa4.offer_id` is present in `oa3` or not - what is the reason for that ? Shortly - would you like to narrow the results when it is not present ? Or just not join it then?

Comment: So basicly, I'm using `oa3` to know which entries are good to continue with, then I'm using `oa4` to apply a new filter on each entries that are present in `oa3`. When it's done I would like to get all the entries that passed this last filter (e.g: an `offer_id` that has its `attribute_id`s `value` set with something else than `"OK"` will not be returned for the rest of the query).

Comment: I've updated the answer basing on your comment, please trywhether it works for your case. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons. Clearly you require oa3.offer_id to be NULL. You do comparison here:

```
oa3.offer_id=oa4.offer_id
```

Comment: But I need to test if `oa4.offer_id` is present or not in `oa3` result set, how can I do this ?